# URL doesn't appear in the references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

`\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}`

```
\begin{document}
\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}  
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}    
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

In the Bibliography.bib file I have included this reference.

```
@article{[PK15],
    Author = {Philip Koopman},
    Volume = {Cornell University, FlexRay Specification Version 2.0, June  2004},
    Url = {http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece649/lectures/23_flexray.pdf},
    Year = {2015}}
```

In the document, In the bibilography section I am getting like this

```
[12] P. Koopman. Cornell University, FlexRay Specification Version 2.0, June 2004, 2015.
```

I am not able to cite the references perfectly. I have complied in the order

```
 PDFLATEX
 BIBTEX
 PDFLATEX
 PDFLATEX
```

Citations are perfect in my document and when I click it, the corresponding reference in my Bibliography section is shown.

Problem is that I am not able to show case the URL present in .bib file. Can someone please explain what is the problem?

The code is a template from internet. There is also a class file and I have also looked in to it. I didn't find anything related to bibilography. I am using TEXmaker.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since you use `natbib`, you should have `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `natbib`, you should choose `abbrvnat` as style, which also supports URLs.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{[PK15],
    Author = {Philip Koopman},
    Volume = {Cornell University, FlexRay Specification Version 2.0, June  2004},
    Url = {http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece649/lectures/23_flexray.pdf},
    Year = {2015}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\cite{[PK15]}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

In the example I use `filecontents` just for keeping it self-contained. Use your own file.

[image]